# index rebuild job is failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I am new to DBA job and in my environment index rebuild job is failing and when I checked reason for failure it is showing  :

> "The transaction log for database 'x' is full due to 'AVAILABILITY_REPLICA'.

We are using SQL Server 2014 with full recovery mode.

Comment: It says transaction log is full .. are you taking log backups ? What is the log_reuse_desc in sys.databases `SELECT [log_reuse_wait_desc], [name]
    FROM [master].[sys].[databases]
    WHERE [name] = N'YourDBName';` ?

Comment: log_backup it is showing

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are using Availability Groups and either one of your replicas is not syncing correctly, or it is getting so far behind that it is causing the log on your primary to grow until is reaches its maximum size (or you run out of disk).

- Check that your secondary replica(s) are online and syncing
  correctly.
- See if you can increase the max size of your transaction
  log on the primary
- Increase the allocated storage on your transaction
  log drive
- Rebuild individual indexes with a wait between them to help
  allow time for log blocks to flush down to your secondary replica(s) (check out [Minion Reindex](http://minionware.net/reindex/) free tool that can help with this)

Comment: secondary replicas are in synchronizing state. they already increased space in disk.

Comment: Then they probably cannot handle the rate of log blocks that are being flushed down to them. Without parallel redo that comes along with 2016 you'll find that operations, like reindexing, take a really heavy toll on a secondary, which leads to this kind of problem. The waits between individual rebuilds will help a great deal.